# boost b2 --layout=system causing LNK1104 error on Visual Studio using CMake

Tags: boost, cmake

I've compiled boost using:

```
b2.exe link=shared runtime-link=shared address-model=32 variant=release --layout=system --stagedir=./stage/win32
```

I'm loading boost components to CMake myself, specifically:

```
find_path(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES boost/config.hpp PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/boost_1_69_0)
message("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_library(Boost INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(Boost PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_library(Boost_filesystem_LIBRARY NAMES boost_filesystem PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../external/boost_1_69_0/stage/win32/lib)
message("${Boost_filesystem_LIBRARY}")

add_library(Boost_filesystem UNKNOWN IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(Boost_filesystem PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
set_target_properties(Boost_filesystem PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${Boost_filesystem_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(Boost INTERFACE Boost_filesystem)
```

When invoking CMake:

```
C:/bla/SW/cmake-template/external/boost_1_69_0
C:/bla/SW/cmake- 
template/external/boost_1_69_0/stage/win32/lib/boost_filesystem.lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/bla/SW/cmake-template/build-windows
```

And last,

```
Link:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\
bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\bla\SW\cmake-template\build-windows
\mylib\Debug\mylib.dll" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO ..\myotherlib\Debug\myotherlib.lib "C:\bla\
SW\cmake-template\external\boost_1_69_0\stage\win32\lib\boost_filesystem.lib" kernel32.lib
user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib /DEF:"C:/bla/SW/cmake-template/build-windows/mylib/mylib.dir/Debug/exports.
def" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PD
B:"C:/bla/SW/cmake-template/build-windows/mylib/Debug/mylib.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLB
ID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:/bla/SW/cmake-template/build-windows/mylib/Debug/
mylib.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH  /machine:X86 /DLL mylib.dir\Debug\mylib.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_69.lib' [
C:\bla\SW\cmake-template\build-windows\mylib\mylib.vcxproj]
```

I don't get it, how come it's trying to link to `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_69.lib` and not to `boost_filesystem.lib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link comes from the auto-ink feature of some of the Boost libraries. You can either adjust the auto-link to use the appropriate naming see macros for controlling this in [Boost Config library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_for_libraries_with_separate_source_code.automatic_library_selection). Or you can turn off the auto-linking with the `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` macro mentioned also in the [Boost Config docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html#boost_config.configuring_boost_for_your_platform.user_settable_options).